# dplyr mutate replace single column values as ifelse

Tags: r, dplyr

The purpose:

I have a dataset that contains many loan processing data (dataset: df). I need to change the character string to numeric data in the field "status". The objective is to change string narrative to a numeric value. I wish to use this status as a response variable in lm() method.

Here is what has been done:

```
df$status <- df$status %>% 
  mutate(status = str_replace("Charged On", "100"))
df$status <- df$status %>% 
  mutate(status = str_replace("Charged Off", "200"))
df$status <- df$status %>% 
  mutate(status = str_replace("Fully Paid", "300"))
df$status <- df$status %>% 
  mutate(status = str_replace("Current", "400"))
df$status <- df$status %>% 
  mutate(status = str_replace("In Grace Period", "500"))
```

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using `case_when` here to generate a new numeric column:

```
df$status <- case_when(
    df$status == "Charged On" ~ 100,
    df$status == "Charged Off" ~ 200,
    df$status == "Fully Paid" ~ 300,
    df$status == "Current" ~ 400,
    df$status == "In Grace Period" ~ 500,
    TRUE ~ -1
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your column "Status" is in a factor format, you can simply change the factor level directly. Here a dummy example mimicking your dataframe:

```r
df <- data.frame(status = rep(c("Charged On","Charged Off","Fully Paid","Current","Grace Period"),10))

        status
1   Charged On
2  Charged Off
3   Fully Paid
4      Current
5 Grace Period
6   Charged On
...        ...
```

We can check that it is a factor format:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   50 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ status: Factor w/ 5 levels "Charged Off",..: 2 1 4 3 5 2 1 4 3 5 ...

> levels(df$status)
[1] "Charged Off"  "Charged On"   "Current"      "Fully Paid"   "Grace Period"
```

Now you can change each factor levels by attributing a new corresponding  value based on the order of factor levels. The new value will be replace all along the column and finally convert it in a numeric format:

```r
levels(df$status) <- c(200,100,400,300,500)
df$status <- as.numeric(as.character(df$status))

>   head(df)                 
  status
1    100
2    200
3    300
4    400
5    500
6    100
```

If your columns is not a factor format, you can convert it to a factor by doing:

```r
df$status <- as.factor(df$status)
```

Comment: Indeed, you're totally right. My mistake to have forgot this parameter. I edit my answer accordingly. Thanks for noticing me this mistake.